# All SMTP mail goes through port 25 which is rejected by gmail and others

Tags: postfix, smtp, mail-server

I set up postfix & dovecot using [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu) and [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/secure-email-server-ubuntu-postfix-dovecot). I can now receive mails OK. However, my outgoing mail is rejected, presumably because it's being sent on port 25. How can I force it to use 587 instead? I read somewhere that setting

```
relayhost=[myhostname.com]:587
```

in main.cf would force this, and indeed it appears to do so. However, this now causes all outgoing mail to be rejected for the new reason that it doesn't recognise the recipient.

I'm pretty sure I can connect through an external relay but I'd prefer to do this on my own box if at all possible.